# Getting error Error occurred in gdi + while compress Image in C#

Tags: file, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to compress image using below code but it gives a error "Error occurred in gdi +".  I have tired 2-3 methods but all are giving same error.

I want to save this compress filed in server path. I am using window Application for same

Method 1 :

```
private void ConvertToThumng(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        //----------        Getting the Image File
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourcePath);

        //----------        Getting Size of Original Image
        double imgHeight = img.Size.Height;
        double imgWidth = img.Size.Width;

        //----------        Getting Decreased Size
        double x = imgWidth / 200;
        int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(imgWidth / x);
        int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(imgHeight / x);

        //----------        Creating Small Image
        System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        System.Drawing.Image myThumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

        //----------        Saving Image
        myThumbnail.Save(targetPath);
    }
```

Comment: Which line in the code gives error?

Comment: It is resoled now. Target path was wrong in my case. Thanks